# Webkit Keyframes: Calculate translate amount using JavaScript or other

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Take a look at this simple [JsFiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/tygx1joL/43/).

What it does is simply inserts a new `li` element with a slide effect from left, when the `ul` display is on `flex` and `inline-block`.

*Something similar to that is Stackoverflow chat avatars when someone joins.*

```
@-webkit-keyframes enter {
  0%   { /*opacity:0;*/ -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
  100% { /*opacity:1;*/ -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moves {
  0%   { /*opacity:0;*/ -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px); }
  100% { /*opacity:1;*/ -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);   }
  }
```

in my `enter` animation, I start with translate `-100%` because I want my item come from left distanced by his size.

and in the `moves` animation, I want to move the whole `ul` to the right, by the size of the entering element.

Now I set it hard-coded, to `50px` because my elements are set to `50px`:

```
  li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

How can I make it calculate the width OR height automatically, on how much to translate the `ul`?

**Example:** *Calculate these 50px automatically*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by animating only the added element by using negative margin:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  var item = $("<li></li>").addClass("enter");
  $("ul").prepend(item).addClass('move');
}, 2000);
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition: all .2s;
}

li {
  --h:50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: var(--h);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.enter {
  animation: enter 1s;
}

@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: calc(var(--h) * -1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    margin-left: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="my-flex-thing">a</li>
  <li class="my-flex-thing">b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but why does margin-left solves it? Any explanation would be great!

Comment: @Jony margin with positive value will push element but margin with negative value will create overlap (it will pull element) .. so making the margin the same as the width will make the element to overlap the next one and when you increase it you will push the next element thus you will make the whole ul to move

Comment: @Jony try the margin animation alone and you will understand better ;)

Comment: Thanks! I know it's not related to this question but, how would you make these boxes go into a new line after reaching the container's max width?

Comment: @Jony you mean using an animation?